# Is there a reversible way to convert from request Id into w3 trace Id

Tags: apex

We are trying to generate a w3 trace Id from Salesforce request Id. However, since Salesforce request Id is 22 bit String and w3 trace Id is 32 bit hex, it is not suitable for a direct convert.

Originally, we were using md5 hashing (many thanks to sfdxfox's help). But the thing is when we reach to our other end, the other team told us they want the algorithm to be reversible - which means they can get the request id based on the trace id.

For me, this is pretty hard. I can think of ways like make an Ascii-like encoding mechanism to encode a-z and A-Z and 0-9. which should be less than 64 and can be held in a 7bit container and use those binary codes to get the hex string. But this approach for both encoding and decoding can be a bit of task though.

Is there an easier reversible way of achieving so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235817/generate-unique-and-reversible-id-for-20-digits-interval

Answer (score 0):

Going on basic math, I don't think it's possible to do this. At least not in the naive way of just converting the input to a number and then encoding it in the other scheme (though all approaches might actually simplify to that in the end. I'm not nearly mathematician enough to say one way or the other).

A 16-byte (32 character) hex string has 2^128 values (= 3.4028 x 10^38)
The 22-character request id from your previous question consists of at least 63 symbols (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and '-'), giving us 63^22 values (= 3.8503 x 10^39)

A 16-byte hex string could only represent around 9% of the possible request id values that Salesforce could potentially generate.

Even your suggested approach runs into this issue.
22 characters * 7 bits per character = 154 bits = 19.25 bytes (which exceeds the 16 bytes you're allotted in the w3 trace-id spec).

Some information would need to be discarded, which means that the process cannot be guaranteed to be reversible.